# How to read HTML Tag in Android?

Tags: android, html-parsing

In my application, I have to make url from getting data from one static url, I have to read value from that page (means from HTML tag i.e. ) and  build new url and display it in webview.

I am facing problem, how to get page source of given url and get particular tag value
like

```
<HTML>
   <Head>
      <Title>ABCDE</Title>
   </Head>
  <div>
   <input type="hidden" name="_MYNAME" id="_MYNAME" value="" />
   <input type="hidden" name="_EVENT" id="__EVENT" value="" />
   <input type="hidden" name="__MYSTATE" id="__MYSTATE" value="">
  </div>
```

I need to read value of tab , I try with htmlcleaner but I was not got success. any suggestion ?

Comment: Can your data url return data in another format instead? Like JSON, XML, etc.?

Comment: no it's not data URL, it's simple website url, for example you can take this page URL, and see viewsource... you got HTML Contain right? i.e. <div class="edit-block">
        <input id="fkey" name="fkey" type="hidden" value="6fbd5f381fda270769e400459395f15a">
        <input id="author" name="author" type="text">
    </div> , I need to read tag <input> and get value="6fbd5f381fda270769e400459395f15a".

Comment: please give me your suggestion, it's very help full to me

Comment: Can you give me up vote for this question because I have to do that as soon as possible... plz....

Answer (score 0):

You can use YQL (Yahoo query Language)  to write query for fetching HTML data.
 YQL returns JSON or XML result which you can read using  HttpGet inside AsyncTask. 
This is developer guide:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/

This is the guide to read JSON response in android:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I am Looking for something like hpple in iOS like that for android.

Answer (score 0):

Just Override the onpagefinished method in WebViewClient for your webview. you just need to write some javascript to get the value fromvthe html page using name or id as simple as we are doing in simple html pages , form the url and load it using js itself

```
 String javascript;

 @Override
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
 super.onPageFinished(view, url);


    javascript="javascript:var yourValue=document.getElementById('tad_id').value;
    window.location = "form your url using yourValue here";"
    wv.loadUrl(javaScript);


 }
```

I am using it to fill the form from my preferences file and working fine for me.

Comment: i.e. <div class="edit-block"> <input id="fkey" name="fkey" type="hidden" value="6fbd5f381fda270769e400459395f15a"> <input id="author" name="author" type="text"> </div> , I need to read tag <input> and get value="6fbd5f381fda270769e400459395f15a"

Comment: @AndroidMobileAppDeveloper just check how to take these thing in js and just replace the js i have writtenthats it and as per i think it is simple js it should work in iOS also try and get back :)